# Algorithm for determine "direction of movement" in a finite field

Tags: algorithm, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to determine the most efficient mechanism for determining direction of movement (i.e., shortest direction between an initial starting value and a second ending value) within a finite field (i.e., a numeric field of integers mod M).

For example, if a given field was defined as positive integers mod 20 and my initial value was 15 then the the following set would be "right/positive/clockwise" - {16, 17, 18, 19, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5} and "left/negative/anti-clockwise" would be {14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6}.

A "brute force" way of doing this would be a linear search, mod 20, starting at the initial value and comparing each value to the new value. E.g.,

```cpp
int field_size = 20, starting_point = 15, new_value = 2;
auto half_field_size = field_size / 2;

// 0 - not set
// 1 - clockwise
// 2 - anti-clockwise
int direction = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= half_field_size; i++){
    if(((starting_point + i) % field_size) == new_value){
        direction = 1;
        break;
    }
}
if(direction == 0) direction = 2;
```

Although this is relatively easy to understand (in terms of code), it seems to be a pretty inefficient way of determining the direction. I feel like there is a more direct way using modular arithmetic but I'm having a hard time coming up with anything consistent.

Answer (score 0):

> I feel like there is a more direct way using modular arithmetic

The main idea is to compare `starting_point - new_value` with `field_size/2` in a modulo fashion.

Consider:

```
direction = (field_size + starting_point - new_value)%field_size*2 >= field_size;
```

`(field_size + starting_point - new_value)%field_size` is either [0...field_size/2) for one direction or [field_size/2...field_size-1] for the other.